# List X is a starter of list Y

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

For lists X and Y,
let's define a term **'X is a starter of Y**' to be
'**there exist a list Z such that Y = Join[X,Z]**'.

Until now I've used following code for **'X is a starter of Y**'

```
Length[X]<=Length[Y] && X==Take[Y,Length[X]]
```

In case Length[X] > Length[Y], the expression Take[Y,Length[X]] produces an error. So the codes became messy.

Above code doesn't look efficient nor beautiful. Is there other good one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your implementation

```
ClearAll[preFixQ1]
preFixQ1[x_, y_] := Length[x] <= Length[y] && x == Take[y,Length[x]]
```

should work without error because if the test `Length[x] <= Length[y]` fails `And` returns `False` without executing the second test. In fact, internal `` GeneralUtilities`PrefixQ `` is implemented the same way.

A cleaner alternative is to wrap the second argument of `Take` with [`UpTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpTo.html) and ( as suggested by imida k in comments) remove the length test:

```
preFixQ[x_, y_] :=  x == Take[y, UpTo@Length[x]]
```

***Examples:***

```
preFixQ[Range[3], Range[5]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
preFixQ[Range[6], Range[5]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

And alternative way to use `MatchQ`:

```
ClearAll[startsWith]
startsWith = MatchQ[Append[___] @ #2] @ # &;

{a, b, c} ~ startsWith ~ {a, b}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
{a, b, c} ~ startsWith ~ {b, a}
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
{a, b, c} ~ startsWith ~ {a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I have searched UpTo in help file. Can I just let
preFixQ[x_, y_] := x == Take[y, UpTo@Length[x]]

Comment: Why do I need  Length[x] <= Length[y] && part still ?

Comment: @imidak, you are right; no need for the length test.

Answer (score 4):

You may simply use a pattern for this:

```
x = {1, 2};
y = {1, 2, 10, 20};
MatchQ[y, {PatternSequence @@ x, ___}]
y = {0, 1, 2, 10, 20};
MatchQ[y, {PatternSequence @@ x, ___}]
y = {1};
MatchQ[y, {PatternSequence @@ x, ___}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `TakeWhile`

```
StartsWith[x_][y_] := 
  TakeWhile[y, MatchQ[Alternatives @@ x]] == x
```

Some tests

```
StartsWith[{"S", "t", "a", "r", "t"}] @ Characters["StartsWith"]
```

True

```
StartsWith[{1}] @ {1, 2}
```

True

```
StartsWith[{2}] @ {1, 2}
```

False

```
StartsWith[{1, 2}] @ Range[5]
```

True

```
StartsWith[{1, 2}] @ Range[0, 5]
```

False

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringStartsQ`:

```
StartsWith[x_][y_] := 
StringStartsQ[StringJoin[ToString /@ y], StringJoin[ToString /@ x]]
```

Testing `StartsWith`:

```
StartsWith[{"S", "t", "a", "r", "t"}]@Characters["StartsWith"]
```

> True

```
StartsWith[{1}]@{1, 2}
```

> True

```
StartsWith[{2}]@{1, 2}
```

> False

```
StartsWith[{1, 2}]@Range[5]
```

> True

```
StartsWith[{1, 2}]@Range[0, 5]
```

> False